# Batch File Move files using multiple text files into another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to loop through multiple text files and copy the files that are in text files. I have set the query to copy for now. When the query works I want to change it to move. Currently this file does nothing.

```
@echo off
set Source=T:\_Epic\Data Conversion\ChartMaxx Docs\LOPE\More\
set Target=T:\_Epic\Data Conversion\MovedFiles\

echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('xcopy "T:\*" T:\ /l') do echo %%a

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: When you sat `"I am trying to create a batch file to loop through multiple text files and copy the files that are in text files."` do you mean you have a filelist that contains file names on each line and you want to read the :"content" of these/that text filelist to then copy files that exist which are listed in the filelist(s)?

Comment: Yes the project is to move a million files into new directories. The files will contain 50K lines in them. I have a file splitter program that has done that part. So now I need this program to do the rest.

Comment: Each new directory should have the name of the file it came from.

Comment: I meant to say ... *"I think of a "filelist" as "a file with a list of file names" but you just need to create a loop of files based on files within some folder."*. Otherwise this should do the trick just for the files within that specific folder.... **`FOR %%A IN ("T:\_Epic\Data Conversion\FileList\*.*") DO (XCOPY /Y /F "%%~A" "%Target%")`** ... If you need to loop different folders then that's what needs to be better understood for standards, etc. to apply to applicable logic for getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate problems jump out.

One - you haven't set a value into `filelist` so likely it won't be found.

Two - your `xcopy` attempts to list the files that would be copied from `T:\*` to `T:\` - you probably wanted `%source%*` to `%target%`.

Comment: So if I add set FileList=T:\_Epic\Data Conversion\FileList\File1.txt to line 5 the program will work. The issue is how can I create a for loop to loop through all the files in the T:\_Epic\Data Conversion\FileList\  folder  ?